# Sharing two SSL certificates with as wildcard and root domains in nginx (same server)

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, wildcard-subdomain

I have purchased a wildcard certificate and a single certificate for my domain structure which is:

```
app.example.com => single
*.app.example.com => wildcard
```

Both these routes should point to the same project directory on same server

*Note: RapidSSL Support said that I had to purchase two as unlike classic domains example.com, my one is app.example.com, so that wildcard won't care my 3 decimal root*

Now, I need to setup in nginx two different certificates. My default one (which works for my wildcard), however not 'app.example.com' as its ssl certificate is not included.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.cer;  // this is my wildcard cert
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;


    root /var/www/example/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name .app.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
 }

 // And for redirect:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name .app.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

How can I divide this into two and include my new certificate for app.example.com and keep wildcard as this?

Comment: RapidSSL just wanted your money, it seems. It's perfectly fine to have both of those names in a single certificate. And many more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two `server` blocks, one for the single domain and one for the wildcard domain. Specify the appropriate `server_name` and `ssl_certificate` directives.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name *.app.example.com;    
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate1.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private1.key;

    ...
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name app.example.com;    
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate2.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private2.key;

    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

You can use an `include` directive to pull common configuration into each block from some other file.